# Prolog query satisfiable but returns false

Tags: prolog, first-order-logic

I have a simple example below of a prolog program I have written, which contains a satisfiable query that always returns false for searches.

```
male(william).
male(harry).

% parent(x,y) - the parent of x is y
parent(william, diana).
parent(william, charles).
parent(harry, diana).
parent(harry, charles).

% Brother - the brother of X is Y
brother(X,Y) :- X\=Y, parent(X,A), parent(Y,A), male(Y).
```

When I ask if two constants are brothers, that works fine, but if I try to find a brother of a constant prolog returns false.

```
?- brother(william,harry).
true

?- brother(william,X).
false.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here `X\=Y` this part lucks logical purity since `\=/2` is non-monotonic. Simply to make it work change the order:

```
brother(X,Y) :- X\=Y, parent(X,A), parent(Y,A), male(Y).
```

to:

```
brother(X,Y) :-  parent(X,A), parent(Y,A), male(Y), X\=Y.
```

But a much better solution would be to use `dif/2` which is preserves purity:

```
brother(X,Y) :- dif(X,Y), parent(X,A), parent(Y,A), male(Y).
```

Comment: Thanks. Using dif(X,Y) fixed the problem. Reading the documentation for dif/2 and \=/2 I think I understand why it didn't work before.